# Install Julia behind proxy on my linux box

Tags: ssl, julia

I am trying to install Julia on a linux box which is behind proxy. The installation of julia is quite easy, but the installation of modules is very exhausting.

1. I tried setting up https_proxy - Failed
2. - sslVerify: false on git level - Failed
3. - JULIA_SSL_NO_VERIFY and other variables like these - Failed.
4. - .curlrc file with insecure in it - Failed.
5. - searched for documentations about the libgit2 and not really helpful documents are available for this on the official page or on the internet.

Really fed up on this. Can someone help me on this please?

Error:
(v1.6) pkg> add IJulia
Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
┌ Warning: could not download https://pkg.julialang.org/registries
└ @ Pkg.Types /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/Types.jl:997
┌ Warning: could not download https://pkg.julialang.org/registries
└ @ Pkg.Types /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/Types.jl:997
Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"   ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:SSL, SSL error: 0xffff8e00 - SSL - An invalid SSL record was received)

Comment: What you get is not an SSL verification error, so dabbling with SSL verification will not help, no matter which variety you try. To what value you set `https_proxy`? Make sure it is something like `http://...` and not something like `https://...`. Make also sure that the proxy actually works, i.e. try with curl or other tool to access other sites.

Comment: Its a good one. I did try but still throwing error. The proxy actually works. I can confirm that.

     Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:SSL, SSL error: 0xffffda9e - X509 - The extensi
on tag or value is invalid : ASN1 - ASN1 tag was of an unexpected value)